# MVC3 doesn't recognize MvcContrib namespace in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, razor, mvccontrib

I'm trying to paginate something with MvcContrib's `Html.Pager()`, but my razor views can't reference the right namespace.

Controller is ok:

```
using MvcContrib.Pagination;
...
public ActionResult List(int? page)
{
    return View(new UserRepository().GetUserList().AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10));
}
```

But, the view can't make sense of either:

```
@using MvcContrib
```

OR

```
@Html.Pager((IPagination)Model)
```

I installed MvcContrib via NuGet. I tried adding `MvcContrib`, `MvcContrib.UI` and `MvcContrib.UI.Html` namespaces to `<pages><namespaces>` in web.config with no luck. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Contrary to WebForms, Razor doesn't use the `<namespaces>` section in `~/web.config`. It uses the `<namespaces>` in `~/Views/web.config`:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MvcContrib"/>
        <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Grid"/>
        <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Pager"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

and then:

```
@model MvcContrib.Pagination.IPagination<SomeViewModel>
@Html.Pager(Model)
```

or you could also add the proper namespace to your view if you prefer:

```
@model MvcContrib.Pagination.IPagination<SomeViewModel>
@using MvcContrib.UI.Pager
@Html.Pager(Model)
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot--I thought NuGet would have done that automagically.

Comment: @Darin After working with Microsoft's WebGrid I decided to give MvcContrib's grid a chance. So far I like it. Way better with lots of customizable points... The only thing I feel is missing is a more consistent documentation section on the site http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation and better integration with an ASP.NET MVC app when the NuGet package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

After adding MvcContrib.dll reference, try this code.

```
@using MvcContrib.UI.Pager
@using MvcContrib.Pagination
@model IPagination    

@Html.Pager(Model)
```

I posted MvcContrib Grid paging,filtering + MVC3 Razor [sample article](http://supremeware.blogspot.com/2011/03/genericviewmodel-based-grid.html) to my blog.