# How to add MVC Contrib Grid in MVC 3.0 Razor

Tags: razor

I am trying to use MVC Contrib grid in MVC 3.0  Razor Framework.In this i add the mvccontrib.dll in my solution.When i try to add the namespace in my View page as
(@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid;),i am getting error that:-The type or namespace name mvccontrib could not be recognized.(r u missing a using directive or assembly reference.)
I also make changes in my [views/web.config] file like below:

    
    
      
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
      
    
  
Still i am getting error:
so pls help me in getting rid of this error.

Comment: thanks for sharing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347038/mvc3-doesnt-recognize-mvccontrib-namespace-in-razor-view for details

Answer (score 0):

Just add the MVCContrib.dll to Reference In the Solution explorer
and how to use and all

Refer this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Grid_Paging_In_MVC3.aspx?display=Print